# Excel Aggregate function that returns date as well

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I am seeking an Excel formula solution to a problem about getting the min/average/max results returning the dates as well as the numbers. Let me present this fictional problem to show the context which my problem exists.

We have a young lady named Betty who wants to be better at guessing or improving her intuition compared to other workers in her office. She set a goal over two weeks to collect data on three different exercises, guessing correctly when picking a coloured pencil out of a bag, guessing correctly when the phone would ring, guessing correctly the new persons name each seen out of 10.  This has been recorded in the attached picture below.

For numbers I have done with the Excel Aggregate function for column H & K & N accordingly but do not know how to get the date to answer the "when" question for the minimum or the maximum. The average date remains blank, so I wanted to answer her question, "when" did Betty not do good (min) Cells G4, J4 and M4 and "when" did Betty do very good (max) Cells G7, J7 and M7. The average remains blank as the data implies the entire range for the two weeks.

[image: Guessing Exercise]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are after, it should return the FIRST instance where the score matches the minimum. I don't know what you want to do where there are multiple days that match the score.

```
=INDEX(Table1[Date],MATCH(H4,Table1[Pencil / 10],0))
```

Comment: Ok will attempt this and let you know tomorrow

Comment: Thank you Dave, I applied your formula as suggested and it solves Betty's problem perfectly.